# Playframework run and Global.onStart

Tags: playframework-2.0

When i run application in DEV mode (play run) my Global.onStart method is not executed.
But if i "play start" my application then Global.onStart runs as it should.

How can i execute Global.onStart by "play run"ing it ?

I use the java version 2.0.2

Comment: Java or Scala ? Which Play version precisely ?

Comment: Please show some code, because I have the same config, and it works as expected.

Comment: In dev mode, onStart is called with the first request

Comment: **CAREFULL** previous message is not true. onStart is called in both cases, DEV and PROD mode.

Answer (score 6):

> > In dev mode, onStart is called with the first request

That was the answer for my question - thank you!

Comment: Untrue. I tried out both with a clean simple code and in **both** cases the code was executed.

Comment: Old question but this answer is actually correct for Play 2.x. In dev mode, `onStart` is called with the first request. The thing to watch for is the automatic recompiling if you make changes to a Java class. Even if you don't manually stop/start the server, Play restarts the server after recompiling so `onStart` will get called again on the next request.

Answer (score 0):

When you add an method in the global object, you might have to kill the current application and restart it in order to reload your changes.

Answer (score -1):

In case you do not have `application.mode` specified in your conf file, starting the application using `play run` and `play start` triggers `dev` and `prod` modes respectively 
[play docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Production).

That said, and taking into account the differences between the modes (more details [here](http://playframework.wordpress.com/2011/03/05/playframework-dev-mode-never-use-in-production/)), namely

> Play starts the application immediately (including any bootstrap
>   jobs), rather  than waiting for the first request, again adding a
>   small performance benefit  for first use

you might want either `play start` or change the mode to PROD in your config file.

Comment: `application.mode` only applies to Play v1.x. The original poster was asking about v2.0.2

Comment: thanks, that is indeed a crucial adjustment, this parameter will be ignored altogether in play! 2.*